# Unable to Display image from Server to custom callout in google maps

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, google-maps, ios7

I want to display image from server to Callout on google maps.for this i used [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage). it is working whenever i click the marker for second time. but i was unable to show image at the first click on the marker.how can resolve this issue.I have created a XIB with imageView and a label for customInfoWindow.

CODE:

```
- (UIView *)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView markerInfoWindow:(GMSMarker *)marker
{
  infoWindow = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"CustomInfoWindow" owner:self options:nil]objectAtIndex:0];
  NSString *imageStr = url;
  [infoWindow.vanityImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageStr]
                                  placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
  infoWindow.name.text = @"Name";
  return infoWindow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this problem is related to  time .

images download and shown to you it takes some time to comes from server to your device/simulator cache memory.
When you use second time it already in your device cache memory so imasge shown to you.

Give some time to your code before shown on UIimageView.

Comment: Can u please explain how can i give delay for this.

Comment: u can try sleep method